# SQL Conversion varchar(255) to int(11) using "alter table"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very new to SQL and I originally setup my table 'item2' with fields that contain numeric values, but are stored in varchar fields.  I need to convert these to a numeric value, I think int(11) will be fine.  I'd like to write a query to convert the fields.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: changed the header to 'using "alter table"' since you could also have it in a "create table as select" statement, see [How to write 'create table ... as select \[some number/function\] as test' in MySQL 5.5 so that the table gets a column of data type int(11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072060/how-to-write-create-table-select-some-number-function-as-test-in-mysql-5/73074191#73074191)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it easily via [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)?

Just view the structure of the table, and edit the required information.

or

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTable` CHANGE `yourTableRow` `yourTableRow` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable CHANGE oldname newname newtype
```

so,

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable CHANGE varcharfield varcharfield INT
```

It looks weird to have the fieldname twice, but MySQL's alter syntax requires a 'new' name for the field being altered, even if it's not going to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should change the data type:

`ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN old_col_name new_col_name column_definition;`