# How to write 'create table ... as select [some number/function] as test' in MySQL 5.5 so that the table gets a column of data type int(11)?

Tags: mysql, select, integer, create-table, mysql-5.5

I build the empty frame of a table in MySQL by taking a huge query, adding a `WHERE 1 = 0` condition (to shrink down the output rows to 0) and running it like the following tiny example:

```sql
create table xzy as 
select convert(2147483647, signed) as test
WHERE 1 = 0
```

I thought taking the [highest possible integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) number would make it an int(11), but it becomes an int(10), and it stays an int(10) when I add just +1 so that it is 2147483648. In my next higher steps, I already landed at bigint, which is not the aim, therefore I started with
`convert(1, int)`. Mind that `cast(1 as integer)` does not seem to be known in  legacy MySQL 5.5 db. Then going over to `convert(1, signed)`  made it int(1) only, as if the `convert` did not change anything. Thus it seems to depend on both number and/or conversion. Or it is perhaps not even possible since I cannot set the length of "signed", it seems.

Now I do not want to try around any further only to find int(11).

I search for the right number/convert parameter that makes the "?" in `select convert(?, signed)` an int(11) so that I do not need to alter the table afterwards to int(11) for that column.

I do this to avoid new code lines. Most of the numeric columns are int(11), therefore the question.

How can

- int(11) = int(11, signed) and
- int(11, unsigned)
  be built just by a `create table ... as select` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the `WHERE 1 = 0` is all about? ... so I'm ignoring that part.

Anyway, add a `+ 1` after the convert achieves the desired goal.

```
create table xzy as 
select convert(2147483647, unsigned) + 1 as test
```

[image]

Information about that was found around the middle of the page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html).
(their example used a `bigint` value)

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7b22f35c9b42816c99e8c2989f1e26c4) (using verson 5.5) with example use.

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 0` is just to get 0 rows since I need to build only the empty frame of the table. New data will get inserted in there afterwards. Made that clearer in the question.

Comment: This has "unsigned" int(11) as the output. The trick is nice but I did not get it to work for "signed" int(11). Not important, though, and in the end, I can still use an alter statement or a change by hand on top, but that would make the trick in the first place unneeded.

Comment: For the (11), needs to be unsigned, or only (10) is available if signed. The 1 difference covers the signed-ness. I don't know that I've seen an int(10) with higher value that the signed range allows, keeping a 4-byte range.

Comment: int(11) seems to be the default in the db that I have at hand, and it seems that it is 'signed' which means that you can use a sign and 10 digits (-2147483648 to +2147483647 is possible). If I alter the `int(11, unsigned)` column to `int(11)`, the "unsigned" is no longer shown. And I think that minus values are possible in the column. Therefore I guess that the `11` means one sign and 10 digits by default. This can likely only be built by inserting the lowest possible int(11) minus-value `convert(-2147483648, signed)`. I tested it, it works, and it works even without the `convert` function. :)